# menu is going out of the page

Tags: css, html

I have created this CSS, but i am getting menu is going out of the page, my width is 100% but the bar is going most of it to the right side out of the page.
Can any one help? and make it width 100%? fit the page. i am using only html and css.

HTML TAG

```
<div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Hotels</li>
            <li>Top Destinations</li>
            <li>Tours & Activities</li>
            <li> Vacations Packages</li>
            <li> Flights</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
```

CSS

```
div#menu li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-black;
    margin-right: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    padding-right: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
div#menu li:last-child{
    border-right: none;
}
div#menu ul{
    background-color: #04b3ae;
    color: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;

}
```

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Comment: added again pls check and advise

Comment: Any chance to use Bootstrap?

Comment: when i tried the same it is not the case...please let us know where it is happening and when

Comment: my menu bar is in the middle of the page, but there is no one related this menu

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo :

```
display: inline-black;
```

It should be :

```
display: inline-block;
```

But why do you use inline-block and float ?

Comment: iff I don't use Inline-block then the menu would be from top to bottm instead left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the padding on your `<ul>` element is causing that. You may set it to `padding-left: 0;`. Just update your styling like this:

```
div#menu ul {
  background-color: #04b3ae;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 0; <-------- Update
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3e33q5vt/)

Comment: I think you meant padding-left: 0px

I have added padding-left: 0px; but it is creating another problem, wtih out any solve

Comment: According to your snippets, the menu was overflowing out of its parent. Removing the padding (left hand side) just solved the problem for me and now it's not overflowing anymore. Thought this would solve the problem for you. Any chance you could provide a fiddle which totally shows off your problem? 'cause as I said, your snippets, wrapped together, just worked well. Of course without the padding. Little hint: `padding: 0` is equal to `padding: 0px`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first off, `div#menu li`'s display is `inline-black`. That's not a thing. I think you're looking for `inline-block`.

Second, you've set your bar's contents to be absolutely positioned-- Meaning it's ignoring stuff, and stuff's ignoring it (though its location is relative to its container). If your bar isn't at the very left edge of the page, and your `ul` isn't at the very left, it'll go to 100%... of the screen's width, not the bar's width, thus making it overflow.

In other words, if your bar or `ul` aren't on the very left edge of the edge, the `ul` will stretch off-screen because its `position:absolute` makes it not really care about its container's width.

Try removing the `position:absolute`. Relative is usually best for stuff like this-- Relative binds the contents to its container, meaning that if the container is 500px, and its contents are 100%, the contents will be 500px over the width of the page.

Comment: yes it was inline-block
I have replaced in to possition: relative; but there is no change

Answer (score 0):

add `position:relative;` to your `div#menu` and `box-sizing: border-box;` to your `div#menu ul`

```css
div#menu {
    position: relative;
}
div#menu li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    padding-right: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
div#menu li:last-child{
    border-right: none;
}
div#menu ul{
    background-color: #04b3ae;
    color: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Hotels</li>
            <li>Top Destinations</li>
            <li>Tours & Activities</li>
            <li> Vacations Packages</li>
            <li> Flights</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
```